# Why won't this macro work in a \caption?

Tags: macros, errors, captions

I created a macro to easily shift into typewriter mode, ala markdown or fancyvrb's "short verbatim" command. It works everywhere but in `\captions`. In that case, TeX fails saying I've exceeded capacity. Is my approach untenable? Below is a MWE. The example outside `\caption`, `!+foo+!`, works fine. The example inside `\caption` fails.

```
\chardef\plus=`+\chardef\bang=`!
\catcode`!=\active\catcode`+=\active
\def\startTTA{\futurelet\next\startTTB} 
\long\def\startTTB#1{\ifx\next+\expandafter\startTTC\else\bang\expandafter#1\fi}
\def\startTTC{\begingroup\ttfamily\global\let+=\stopTTA\global\let!=\bang}
\def\stopTTA{\futurelet\next\stopTTB}
\long\def\stopTTB#1{\ifx\next!\expandafter\stopTTC\else\plus\expandafter#1\fi}
\def\stopTTC{\endgroup\global\let+=\plus\global\let!=\startTTA}
\let!=\startTTA\let+=\plus
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
!+foo+!
\begin{figure}
\tracingmacros=1\tracingcommands=2
\caption{!+foo.+!}
\tracingmacros=0\tracingcommands=0
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Suggestions for improving this macro are welcome as well!

Comment: Perhaps you might enlighten us as to the aim of all of this.

Comment: `!+foo+!` should be an abbreviation for `\texttt{foo}`. I guess that `\let\?\texttt` and `\?{foo}` is quite simpler.

Comment: @JosephWright I am writing a document with a lot of typewriter type (for code samples). I found myself using fancyvrb's "`DefineShortVerb`" command with the hash symbol (`#`) so I could write things like "`#int x = 0#`" and have it come out in typewriter. That breaks in captions, though, and I have to resort to `\texttt{...}`.

`\texttt` isn't so burdensome, but I thought it would be fun to figure out how do it "markdown" style, and delimit typewriter text using something "!+ ... +!".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the definition of `\startTTB` and `\stopTTB` with an argument; moreover, the active `!` and `+` should be protected against expansion in write operations:

```
\makeatletter
\chardef\plus=`+\chardef\bang=`!
\catcode`!=\active\catcode`+=\active
\def\startTTA{\futurelet\next\startTTB}
\def\startTTB{\ifx\next+\expandafter\startTTC\expandafter\@gobble\else\bang\fi}
\def\startTTC{\begingroup\ttfamily\protected\def+{\stopTTA}\protected\def!{\bang}}
\def\stopTTA{\futurelet\next\stopTTB}
\def\stopTTB{\ifx\next!\expandafter\stopTTC\expandafter\@gobble\else\plus\fi}
\def\stopTTC{\endgroup}
\protected\def!{\startTTA}\protected\def+{\plus}
\makeatother
```

It's not necessary to do global redefinitions. With the two `\@gobble` commands, the `+` or `!` characters are swallowed.

A shorter set of macros will do the same:

```
\chardef\plus=`+\chardef\bang=`!
\catcode`!=\active\catcode`+=\active
\protected\def!{\startTTA}\protected\def+{\plus}
\def\startTTA{\futurelet\next\startTTB}
\def\startTTB{\ifx\next+\expandafter\startTTC\else\bang\fi}
\long\def\startTTC+#1+!{\begingroup\ttfamily
  \let+\plus\let!\bang#1\endgroup}
```

However, I don't see where this is more efficient than declaring

```
\def\?+#1+?{\texttt{#1}}
```

and writing

```
\?+foo+?
\caption{\?+foo+?}
```

Comment: But the output for `!+foo+!` yields `\texttt{+foo!}` instead of `\texttt{foo}`.

Comment: @Werner Yes, you're right.

Comment: That pretty much worked -- I needed to add a command to gobble the trailing `+` or `!` (on start and stop) to `\startTTC` and `\stopTTA`, or extra characters showed up in the output. 

Thanks very much!

Comment: "That" in my previous comment refers to the first block of code given by @egreg. While the last macro given does the same thing, I still want to use my silly markdown syntax.

Comment: @JustinBailey Does the shorter version work? It should, but I've not made extensive testing.

Comment: Yep, that one works as well.